# MVC Save default image from folder to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Good day!

How can you save a default image from a project folder to database?

What I want is that a default image should be saved directly to database as soon as the button save was clicked. Is it possible to be done using `<input type=file src="~/source_here"/>`?

**MODEL**

```
public partial class tbl_Picture
{
public string picture_id { get; set; }
public byte[] picture { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<input type="file" src="~/image/seal.png" name="image1" id="image1"/>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Views(tbl_Picture pic, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    tbl_Picture pict = new tbl_Picture();
    pict.picture = new byte[image1.ContentLength];
    image1.InputStream.Read(pict.picture, 0, image1.ContentLength);
    db.tbl_Picture.Add(pict);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

What I tried was to provide the input file a default url of the photo so that the photo would be saved to the database. But all I get is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which line that `NullReferenceException` thrown? Is that `HttpPostedFileBase image` contains null value so that `image1.ContentLength` throws NRE?

Comment: Additionally `<input type="file" />` doesn't have `src` attribute which can be pointed to image path, are you want to preview uploaded image before saving using `<img>` tag like `<img id="image" src="#" ... />`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I just wanted the image from my project folder to be saved into my database

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase image` shouldn't that be `HttpPostedFileBase image1` since your input is `name="image1"` in the HTML. I think they have to match just like any other HTML form field. And yeah what's the "src" bit in the `<input` tag about? That makes no sense.

Comment: Also if you want to push saved image in server to DB, just use `ReadAllBytes` with `Server.MapPath` to convert it as `byte[]` so that it can be saved as `varbinary` data with EF's `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @ADyson I was trying to get the image from my project folder then be saved to the db. I am sorry I don't know how to properly do it

Comment: First a `<input type="file" ... />` is for the user to select a file on their device and upload it the the server (and you cannot set the value of a file input in code). `src` is not a valid attribute for a file input and does nothing except create invalid html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks sr.

Comment: @MaceMunch you mean a project folder on the server? As Stephen said, an `<input type="file"` is for the user to select a file from their own machine and upload it, not to select from the server. Do you want the user to be able to choose which file to save into the database? You'll have to write some C# code to read the list of files from the server's disk and then in the view you would list all the possible files they can select from. Provide a way for them to select (e.g. checkbox or something) and submit the form. Then when you get back the selected filename you can save it to the DB

Comment: @ADyson I mean a photo is in a project folder. I wanted it only be selected then saved to database. Thanks for the info sir

Comment: yes, you keep repeating that without actually providing any more information. Where is the project folder? On the client or on the server? That's what I asked. If it's on the server then you can use the process I just described to allow the user to select which one to save.

Comment: @ADyson It is located in my project. I created a folder then added the image there. I will just do what was suggested here. thanks sr

Comment: again...where is your "project"? You mean you asp.net "project"? Then it'll be on the server. Did you understand my question? Do you understand the difference between client and server? P.S. It's no longer a "project" really when it's deployed on a server, it's just some compiled code in a folder. The project files from visual studio don't get copied to the server. Hence why I was unsure what you mean by project - I thought it could maybe be your photography "project" in some folder on a laptop or something. Please try to answer questions directly and with the right terminology, thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson It is not yet deployed in my server. It is not yet published. Just a project in my pc saved in my drive c: sir. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: No problem. It just helps to use the right terminology, then everyone is clear. Even if the code is still in your PC, when you run it, your PC runs a server program to accept the HTTP requests. Then your browser is the client. Even though everything is on one physical machine, the client-server architecture still exists - there are still folders which are conceptually part of the "server-side" of the application. It's useful to keep that conceptual model in your head I think.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from the comments section, all I did was to combine `ReadAllBytes` with `Server.MapPath()`. The output would look like this,

```
model.pic = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/image/seal.png"));
```

Thanks for the help.